# is there any way to apply wysiwyg in a jtextarea?

Tags: swing

I'm trying to put my system info (obtained from the dos command "systeminfo >sysinfi.txt") in a `JTextarea`. The outout of this command is well alligned in a text file, but as I add it to `jtextarea` it becomes scrambled.

Is there any way to apply wysiwyg in a `JTextarea` ?

code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("systeminfo ");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
{
 jTextArea1.append("\n"+line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which gives me WYSIWYG,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TestTextarea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String line;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);


        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("systeminfo ");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                textArea.append("\n" + line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" + e.getMessage());
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```